# Heap corruption detected, memory is still being written after end of heap buffer

Tags: c++, visual-studio, class, visual-c++

So I am doing this assignment about classes and whatnot. Everything compiles and i get the expected output, but I keep getting an error that says
"HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED..... CRT detected that the application wrote memory after the end of heap buffer."

When I go back into my code after this, one line is highlighted by green and says "Buffer overrun while writing to owner"

Here is the code:

```
void bank::setOwner(const char* nameOwner) 
{
    if (owner != nullptr)
        delete[] owner;
    int i = 0;
    while (nameOwner[i++] != '\0');
    owner = new char[i];
    while (i >= 0) {
        owner[i--] = nameOwner[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: All questions here should have all relevant information ***in the question itself as plain text***. Links can stop working at any time making questions meaningless. Code, data, or errors shown as images cannot be copy/pasted; or edited or compiled for further research and investigation. Can you [edit] this question, removing and replacing all links and images with all relevant information as plain text? All code must meet all requirements of a [mre]. You'll find many other questions here, with a [mre], in plain text. Please use them as an example for how your question should look.

Answer (score 0):

Let me introduce to the great [rubber ducky](https://kenzie.snhu.edu/blog/what-is-rubber-duck-debugging/).

Now that introductions are made, you can use its infinite wisdom to help detect problems and buggy code. The conversation could go like this:

You:

> *Rubber ducky, what will happpen in the lines 7 through 9 if, let's say, `i` is 10?*

RD:

> *Well, an array of 10 chars named `owner` will be allocated in line 7, then in line 9, in the very first iteration you will be writing in `owner[10]`, that is index 11 in an array that can only take 10 elements.*

You:

> *Is that bad?*

RD:

> *Yes, you will be writing outside the bounds of the array. That means you can be writing in memory that may not belong to your program, and even if it does, it will lead to something we call [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub), and that's definitely very bad.*
>
> *I noticed you are using raw pointers in your code, is that needed? Can you think of other tools you could use that would make more sense here?*

You:

> I could surely use `std::string`:
>
> ```
> //std::string owner;
>
> void bank::setOwner(const std::string& nameOwner) 
> {
>    owner = nameOwner;
> }
> ```

Comment: Your rubber ducky seems very oracular; mine is much more socratic.